# JSON "No serializer found for" issue

Tags: json, spring, serialization

I am getting a really strange error when running some Spring JSON tests.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.commons.io.input.ReaderInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource["inputStream"])
```

As ReaderInputStream is public It's not a setVisibility issue on my object mapper so I am not entirely sure what the problem is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the object you want to serialize?

Comment: It was trying to serialize a ReaderInputStream, the problem was that I created a new Message converter without making sure it only wrote on the desired type of objects